# Bean creation throws exception at the build time

Tags: spring, rest, maven, cxf

Hi all I have an exception thrown when building application to be deployed in tomcat, and I am suspecting pom.xml is the source as I found in the net that dependencies are the responsible causes for this  exception, anyhow, here is my stack trace:

```
GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with      
name 'productWebService': Error setting property values; nested exception is   
 org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested   
PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:

PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException:    
 Property 'serviceBeans' threw exception; nested exception is   
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:    
 org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested    
PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException:    
Property 'serviceBeans' threw exception; nested exception is     
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:   
org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
at .....    


13 mars 2014 08:56:27 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Error listenerStart
13 mars 2014 08:56:27 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Erreur de démarrage du contexte [/WebApp] suite aux erreurs précédentes
13 mars 2014 08:56:27 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
13 mars 2014 08:56:27 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
13 mars 2014 08:56:27 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
13 mars 2014 08:56:27 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6330 ms
```

here is my pom.xml:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    net.ma.s2m
    WebApp
    war
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    WebApp Maven Webapp
    http://maven.apache.org

```
<properties>
    <cxf.version>3.0.0-milestone2</cxf.version>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <finalName>WebApp</finalName>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please add the output from mvn dependency:tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring 3.0.5 does not have that method. Try upgrading your spring version. There could be some incompatibilities between the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely one of your jar files is calling the function which doesnt exist in the `Spring 3.0.5` version that you use.

It also might be due to jar conflicts where an older jar file expects an older Spring version than `3.0.5` which isnt on your classpath too.

You can check your dependency tree through the command line to find about expected jar files as transitive dependencies by other jar files as well as to understand about conflicts.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: Hi, I fixed the problem. I upgraded the spring version to 3.2.0 and everything work fine. I removed the dependencies from the pom.xml file and then add the CXf Apache 3.0.0 library to the class path and it worked fine it is here where I noticed that the version of spring cxf is using. so I return back to pom.xml and add the new version of spring.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Spring version (4.2.5) has also removed the above method.

See [Unable to deploy the project in Apache tomcat with apache cxf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393291/unable-to-deploy-the-project-in-apache-tomcat-with-apache-cxf/34398060#34398060)

You have to either upgrade to Apache CXF to 3.0 or stick with an older Spring version (for example 4.1.5).