# Red5 1.05 on Windows Server 2012 R2 startup fails

Tags: java, windows, red5

I use Avchat which in the past required setup-Red5-1.0.0-RC1 to work properly.  I had been running Avchat on this version fine for the past year and recently upgraded to the latest version of Avchat which requires Red5 to be upgraded to 1.05.  Since upgrading my red5 will not startup, it stops during the startup.  Please see log.

```
Bootstrap exception: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.bootStrap(Bootstrap.java:123)
        at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:48)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'red5.common' defined
in class path resource [red5.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.facto
ry.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter': Invocation of init method failed; nested except
ion is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegis
try.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListable
BeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplic
ationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.red5.server.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:69)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter': Invoc
ation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isCgli
bProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegis
try.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListable
BeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplic
ationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.red5.spring.Red5ApplicationContext.refresh(Red5ApplicationContext.java:36)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractRe
freshableConfigApplicationContext.java:150)
        at org.red5.spring.Red5ApplicationContext.afterPropertiesSet(Red5ApplicationContext.java:30)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowi
reCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:166)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerLazyInit(MBeanExporter.java:681)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:573)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:527)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterPropertiesSet(MBeanExporter.java:413)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowi
reCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        ... 30 more
Bootstrap exit
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your output would seem to indicate that your cglib is missing or does not support the method which is missing:

```
NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)
```

Comment: Hi Mondain,

Thank you for the quick response.  It's not clear to me how to fix this.  do you have any recommendations?  I can switch back to the 1.0.0-RC1 on the same server and it instantly starts working, this error is occurring once I switch to 1.05.  The Java version is 8u40
Thanks

Comment: Check to see if you have cglib 2.2.2 in your red5/lib directory

Comment: It could also be an incompatibility with spring; make sure you have the right spring version for your build of red5. Heres a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373751/bean-creation-throws-exception-at-the-build-time

Comment: Spring 4.0.8 is currently what we use: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/blob/master/pom.xml#L63