# ApacheCXF 3.1.4 and Spring 4.2.4 compatability

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, cxf, hudson

I am trying to upgrade my libraries: ApacheCXF 2.7.7 --> 3.1.4. Spring 2.5.5 --> 4.2.4.

My Hudson build keeps failing because it cannot find packages/classes, *org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext*, for example. The classpath in cxf-manifest.jar, as part of ApacheCXF, refers specifically to Spring 4.1.7 jars.

I've tried loading both Spring 4.1.7 and 4.2.4 versions, but no joy. (Is loading multiple lib versions even possible?).

I've tried removing cxf-manifest.jar from the classpath/buildpath. Eclipse is happy with that and it finds the desired classes in the Spring 4.2.4 jars, but Hudson is still not happy.

I've considered moving to Spring 4.1.7, but I don't see the point of upgrading partially.

Is ApacheCXF 3.1.4 specifically incompatible with Spring 4.2.4? And how would I get Hudson to be happy with the upgraded libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I forgot to add the specific directory containing the Spring jars to my build.xml script.

ApacheCXF 3.1.4 **IS** compatible with Spring 4.2.4

**Edit:** Apparently I was wrong.

Comment: I think that this answer cannot be considered the correct answer, see the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393291/unable-to-deploy-the-project-in-apache-tomcat-with-apache-cxf - A guy of the Spring team himself has clearly said that "That version of cxf is not compatible with Spring 4.2.x - those methods were deprecated in Spring 3.1 and were removed in Spring 4.2."