# issue due to version compatibility with spring and web-service request responses

Tags: cxf, spring-4, spring-2.5

I am working in migration project which uses spring 2.5.6 and webservice running on spring 4.2.3.Release
Since Xml processor cannot be changed due to some confidentiality with clients iam trying to send the request object from processor and get the response object using webservice. I will come to the point. Is it possible to use different versions/dependencies for the request and response. 
Request being sent from 2.5.6 and response from 4.2.3.release.
I have tried some thread which not working [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373751/bean-creation-throws-exception-at-the-build-time)

Error Trace:

```
xception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.SpringAopClassHelper.getRealClassInternal(SpringAopClassHelper.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ClassHelper.getRealClass(ClassHelper.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.setCommonProviders(ProviderFactory.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProviderFactory.setProviders(ClientProviderFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.initFactory(ProviderFactory.java:129)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProviderFactory.createInstance(ClientProviderFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.initClient(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.createWithValues(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:321)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:264)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactory.create(JAXRSClientFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactory.create(JAXRSClientFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactory.create(JAXRSClientFactory.java:49)
    at com.cpglogistics.isa.ws.rest.client.OrderWSClient.getOrderBySAPOrderNO(OrderWSClient.java:50)
```

Comment: if you need more information i can explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some versions of CXF and spring incompatible for working togetger. In my opinion you should use same version of spring for each module .For spring 2.5.6 you can use 2.7 version of CXF. This error not only causes for spring version.